# iOS Project with CocoaPods in SVN Failed when doing pod install/update

Tags: svn, cocoapods

So we decided to integrate CocoaPods in our existing project which is under SVN. My teammate had set it up successfully and he can just build the project just fine.

But when I checked-out the project and did a `pod install`, I get this error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using ASIHTTPRequest (1.8.1)
Using Base64nl (1.1)
Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.7.1)
[!] Pod::Executable clone '/Users/me/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/2cdc3c53ee617444d0d6cd7730e598cd77a19eb2' 
'/Users/me/Desktop/MyFiles/iOS/MyProject/Pods/Facebook-iOS-SDK'

sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I did try removing the Caches/CocoaPods/Github directory and pod install/update, but still it doesn't work.

I also found out that according to `svn status`, I have missing directories:

```
MyProject/Pods/Headers  
MyProject/Pods/BuildHeaders
```

// btw, Does this not automatically added when I pod install?

And lastly I thought that it's a problem with our internet connection here, but when I did try to pod install with another Project it works just fine.

What could be other setup am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a fresh `svn checkout` of the project, then when that completes successfully, do an `svn update` on it immediately. You shouldn't get anything new (unless someone has committed to the project while you were checking it out). After that, run your pod install.

Comment: i did try checking new project and pod install. it was the svn update that i missed

Comment: just found the workaround."Devs will have to remember to run pod install after initial checkout or when pulling an update with dependency changes. Small annoyance but worth it."https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/247

Comment: Makes sense though, doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are having this issue because your project path contained single quotes or spaces.

This issue has been already [reported to cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1344).